# How to store result from Find::File into array

Tags: perl

I want to list the file in directory and subdirectory. I use perl File::Find. Is it possible for me to store the result into an array?

Here is the code

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

my $location="tmp";

sub find_txt {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;

    if ($F =~ /txt$/ ) {
       push @filelist, $F;
       return @filelist;
    }
}


my @fileInDir = find({ wanted => \&find_txt, no_chdir=>1}, $location);
print OUTPUT @fileInDir
```

the code above doesn't display the output

Comment: My Fite::Find::Closures module has several examples. It's designed such the you can lift the code directly into your own code without relying on the module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just `push` into an array declared outside:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

my $location = "tmp";

my @results;
my $find_txt = sub {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;

    if ($F =~ /txt$/ ) {
        push @results, $F;
    }
};


find({ wanted => $find_txt, no_chdir=>1}, $location);
for my $result (@results) {
    print "found $result\n";
}
```

The return value of the `wanted` callback [is ignored](https://perldoc.pl/File::Find#The-wanted-function). `find` itself has no documented or useful return value either.

Comment: but I want to use the array outside the subroutine

Comment: @daffodil You can.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, this is much more straightforward with [Path::Iterator::Rule](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Iterator::Rule).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Path::Iterator::Rule;

my $location = 'tmp';
my $rule = Path::Iterator::Rule->new->not_dir->name(qr/txt$/);
my @paths = $rule->all($location);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
my @fileInDir = find({ wanted => \&find_txt, no_chdir=>1}, $location);
```

with

```
my @fileInDir;
find({ wanted => sub { push @fileInDir, find_txt(); }, no_chdir=>1 }, $location);
```

and add the missing

```
return;
```

aka

```
return ();
```

to `find_txt`. Unlike the solution in the earlier answer, this allows you to have reusable and conveniently located "wanted" subs.